# Improve MySQL concurrent updates

Tags: mysql, update, locking, concurrency

Are there any suggestions to run the concurrent updates on a table (100+ concurrent updates on a specific row)? Same row, like updating the clicks count for an user.

```
UPDATE `tbl` 
SET `cli`=`cli`+ 1,`updated_at`='2023-12-08 13:19:09' 
WHERE `id` = 3145
```

ID column is a primary key. And many of the sessions are in lock_wait (row lock wait).

Comment: i have adjusted the innodb_sync_array_size, seems a bit improvement

Comment: innodb_sync_array_size has no effect on lock contention. If you observe any difference after changing that value, it must be coincidence.

Comment: Yes, That is correct. Its not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL needs to serialize access to a given row. It does this by locking the row, or more accurately the primary key index for that row.

To allow more clients to update the row, you need to minimize the time of the transaction. This means they are still serialized, but if they commit and release their locks at least quickly enough as the rate of incoming updates, then the throughput can continue without queuing.

Suggestions:

1. Use autocommit. This still starts and commits a transaction for the update, but it minimizes the duration of the transaction.
2. If you can't use autocommit, i.e. if you use an explicit transaction, then start and commit it as promptly as possible. Don't let the transaction go on uncommitted any longer than necessary.
3. Set isolation level to minimize gap locks, just in case sessions that are updating different rows are interfering with each other.

   ```
   SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
   ```

If this still doesn't support enough throughput to keep up with the incoming requests, then you must use some other technology to track your counters. For example, a key-value data store like Redis or DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

- Move active counters like that into a table of their own.  This avoids (to some extent) conflicting with other activity on the table.
- Do not bump a counter inside of a bigger transaction.  As Bill suggests, let it stand alone as its own transaction (`AUTOCOMMMIT = ON` and no `BEGIN`).